# autoplay youtube in featherlight lighbox when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

How can I get a youtube video to autoplay in featherlight lightbox when a button is clicked and closed when the close button is clicked.

This doesn't seem to work

```
<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />

<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>  </iframe>
```

Comment: That won't work because the button doesn't actually *does* something.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/dyLAC

This just adds autoplay property to iframe-link.

To close it, try and make a button that removes the whole iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {

    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work. the youtube video doesn't play automatically in the lightbox.